# Solve $x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Solve:
>
> $$x^2+x+1\equiv0\pmod5$$

**My attempt:**

Our proffesor told us that if we have $ax^2+bx+c\equiv\pmod p$ we need to multiply by $4a$, to get form of $(\text{ something})^2\equiv D\pmod p$.

$p$ is a prime and $\gcd(4a,p)=1$, so I tried to do that here:

$$4x^2+4x+4\equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

But now

$$(2x+1)^2+3\equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

$$(2x+1)^2\equiv -3 \pmod 5$$

Comment: Well $-3\equiv 2 \pmod 5$, and as lab says $2$ is not a square mod $5$

Comment: That's an elegant way of solving this problem, multiplying by 4. One generally thinks of brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any integer $a,$

$$a\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2\pmod5\implies a^2\equiv0,1,4\pmod5\not\equiv-3$$

Comment: So, there is no solution?

Comment: @Error404,  Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The usual formula $$x = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1^2 - 4\cdot 1 \cdot 1}}{2}$$ still works for integers modulo a prime, you just have to interpret the square root and the division differently. And in this case $\sqrt{-3}$ doesn't exist in the integers modulo $5$, so there are no roots.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, there's this trick for solving quadratic congruences: if $\gcd(n,2a)=1$, then:

$$ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0\pmod{n}$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 4a}\iff (2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{n}$$

In this case,

$$x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$

$$\stackrel{\cdot 4}\iff (2x+1)^2\equiv -3\equiv 2\pmod{5},$$

contradiction, because $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $5$ (to see this, notice $(5k\pm 1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $(5k\pm 2)^2\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, $(5k)^2\equiv 0\pmod{5}$).

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, there is yet another way:
Since $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1,$ we find that a solution to the equation must also satisfy $x^3-1\equiv0\pmod5.$
But if $x^3\equiv1\pmod5,$ then clearly $x^4\equiv x\pmod5.$ Also, [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) says that $x^4\equiv1\pmod5$ if $5\not\mid x.$ Thus the solution is either $x\equiv0\pmod5$ or $x\equiv x^4\equiv1\pmod5,$ while these two cases can easily be seen not to satisfy the equation in question. Therefore there are no solutions.

Hope this helps.